# Java equals() equivalent in PHP

Tags: java, php

I want know whats Java [equals()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equals.htm) equivalent in PHP?

I want use it in if statement.

```
public function categories($lang) {
    echo 'LANG IN INDEX CONTROLLER CATEGORIES BEFORE: ' . $lang.'<br>';
    if ($lang !== "az" || $lang !== "en" || $lang !== "ru") {
        $lang = 'az';
    }
    echo 'LANG IN INDEX CONTROLLER CATEGORIES AFTER: ' . $lang;
    $db = new DBClass();
    $categories = $db->select("CALL SELECT_CATEGORY('$lang')");
    return $categories;
}
```

I sent **$lang** parameter 'en' and result 
LANG IN INDEX CONTROLLER CATEGORIES BEFORE: en
LANG IN INDEX CONTROLLER CATEGORIES AFTER: az

I tryed [strcmp()](http://php.net/strcmp).

This code does't work, whats worng? How can I use **==** or **strcmp()** in if statement?

Comment: @John Conde is right. FYI: If you want to use strcmp have a look at the documentation -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php . strcmp returns 0 if both strings are equal.

Comment: We all love Java but unfortunately in PHP you have to get a little "dirty". You could always just write your own  equals(str1, str2) method.

Comment: @lukescomputers I guess OP's asking for something like `String#equals` for string comparison but the problem is that OP's problem is about how to check that a string is not part of a set of strings.

Comment: Make a general function that returns a Boolean. Its parameters would he a string and a set of strings. Boolean inArray(str1, str[]) (I know that this isn't proper syntax but I think you get the idea)

Comment: @lukescomputers that function already exists in PHP. Check my answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ah yes, I forgot about that function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
if ($lang !== "az" || $lang !== "en" || $lang !== "ru") {
```

will always be true because because a scalar variable can't have three values at once. You need to use `&&`:

```
if ($lang !== "az" && $lang !== "en" && $lang !== "ru") {
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this in PHP is using [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)to check if a variable is in a set of values. Since you want to check that `$lang` is not `"az"`, `"en"` or `"ru"`, then just negate the result:

```
$forbidden_langs = array("az", "en", "ru");
if (!in_array($lang, $forbidden_langs)) {
    //your code goes here...
}
```